# Access to Windows files from Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: files

My Windows XP partition became corrupted recently, however I fortunately had installed Ubuntu 11.10 in a dual boot fashion. How can I access my Windows files from Ubuntu?

Comment: The possibility to access files on a "corrupted" partition entirely depends on the nature of the damage done. What exactly happened?

Answer (score 1):

CLick on the *Places* option in the top left corner of your screen and click on the partition in whick windows is installed.Thats it.

EDIT-Sorry that is for 10.10. check this article
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountwindows  or
http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Just open Nautilus and look for windows installed drive.

Comment: dats what i have posted bro. its in the link i provided.